# How to get path to provided visual studio "lib.exe" executable in CMake?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, cmake

How to get path to provided visual studio "lib" executable (that can be found in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\`) from CMake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full path to `lib.exe` is not directly available. But you could derive it from `CMAKE_LINKER`:

```
get_filename_component(_vs_bin_path "${CMAKE_LINKER}" DIRECTORY)
```

Or you could do this via a script like CMake does this in [`Windows-GNU.cmake`](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/Platform/Windows-GNU.cmake#L155).